# PHP encoding string from latin1 (ISO-8859-1) to UTF8

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

For some reason an old database was storing strings which were normal UTF8 into a table that was latin1 (ISO-8859-1).
So the string "međuvremenu" became "meÄ‘uvremenu"

Now, I know there is a way to convert it via mysql query into a normal one, which is:

`convert(cast(convert(text using  latin1) as binary) using utf8)`

What I need is the exact same thing but to do it solely in php, since I cannot temper with this database (otherwise I'd just update the entire column.

I guess it is possible with mb_convert_encoding but didn't have luck so far.

Edit: Do not associate this question with the one that provides mysql solution as I explicitly stated I need php-only solution.

Comment: Try `mb_convert_encoding("meÄ‘uvremenu", "Windows-1252", "UTF-8")` if you are looking for pure `php` solution…

Comment: Thanks, it seems thats exactly what I needed.
But how is that Windows-1252?

Comment: The `‘` character (U+2018,  _Left Single Quotation Mark_) isn't defined in  `latin1`.